# opening json file error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm a very beginner in programming and I'm stuck with this "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" error. I want to load a JSON file located in the same folder as my python script.

```
with open("dictionnaire.json") as file:
data = json.load(file)
```

I'm using python 3.9.0, I don't understand what's wrong. Could you me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the path like this :

```
 with open("./path_to_json_file/data.json", 'r') as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      f.close()



for key, value in data.items():
   print("key: {} | value: {}".format(key, value))
```